# Google Maps Javascript API v3 map displays on desktop browser but won't display on mobile browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm developing an app that displays a map using Google Maps Javascript API v3, and it displays the way it's supposed to on my desktop browser, but it doesn't on my mobile's browser.

So, I've checked this: [My Google Map javascript code displays on desktop browser but not my mobile phone browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16029133/my-google-map-javascript-code-displays-on-desktop-browser-but-not-my-mobile-phon)

And this: [Javascript Google Maps API loading in Web Browser but not Android Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26771549/javascript-google-maps-api-loading-in-web-browser-but-not-android-browser)

It was everything I could find relating to my issue, but both of these had a similar problem which was that they were passing navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition() as a parameter to their initialize function or something like that, instead of passing initialize as the callback for getCurrentPosition(). I've also seen someone with the same issue that was being caused because they were asking for the current position before the document had loaded, which is also not my issue, for I'm calling getCurrentPosition() from jQuery's $(document).ready().

Here's my code, any help is greatly appreciated:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>        
    <script type="text/javascript" 
            src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true">            
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize(location) {
      console.log(location);
    var currentLocation= new google.maps.LatLng(location.coords.latitude, location.coords.longitude);
    var mapOptions = {            
      center: currentLocation,
      zoom: 17,
      disableDefaultUI:true,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), 
       mapOptions);
    var marker= new google.maps.Marker({
        position:currentLocation,
        map: map
    });
  }    

  $(document).ready(function(){
     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initialize);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Does the map display at all on the mobile version?

Comment: It doesn't show at all, but I've already figured it out, I'll post an answer soon

Comment: i do face the similar issue my app works in desktop browser, but not in android mobile chrome browser. if anyone resolve this issue, please post the solution. Thanks

Comment: @Prithvi The issue isn't related to the Google Maps API. It's actually a problem that has to do with the "navigator.geolocation" on mobile browsers. I tried to recover the code with which I solved this, but wasn't able to do it. Try looking into a different way to get location.

Comment: @sbacaro . In mobile browsers/Desktop. the site should be on HTTPS. if not, geolocation doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also encountered the same problem using navigator.geolocation which seem to work well on PC. I tried accessing it on my phone but keeps showing error. 
I finally resolved the issue by adding https:// to the address I was visiting on my mobile. Even if you don't have an SSL on your site, just add https:// to the url and everything will be fine.

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answer because it solved it for you and I no longer work on the project I initially asked this for.